# mysql search query by each digit of the search keyword

Tags: php, mysql

I have a numbers in database

```
    88746
    65654
    78655
    67856
    09958
    55640
```

I need to get out put when i search

'786'  means search key is 786

```
    search result        
    88746
    78655
    67856
```

The output criteria if it is any occurrence 7  8  6  in that number groups,means if i search 5 that is the search key is 5 then we need to show all rows with number 5 is occurred. example keyword is 5 out put is 65654,78655,67856,09958,55640 means the digit 5 occurred in all that set of numbers

I need a mysql query for this challenge

I tried a query

```
select * from plates where number LIKE %786%

        --------
        number |
        ------ |
        88746  |
        65654  |
        78655  |
        67856  |
        09958  |
```

OUTPUT

```
        number |
        ------ |
        88746  |
        78655  |
        67856  |
```

Comment: These are strings.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check for each individual character if it is in the larger number.

```
SELECT * FROM plates
WHERE number LIKE '%7%'
   AND number LIKE '%8%'
   AND number LIKE '%6%'
```

If your search input consists of more or less characters you have to change your query. What I suggest is you have some sort of template string `"number like '%{$i}%'"` and use `$i` top put the number into it and then append it to the existing query.

**Example:**
Search input is 8765.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM plates WHERE ";
$pattern = "number LIKE '%%%s%%' ";
$input = "8765";
$c = strlen($input); // 8765 returns 4, 456 returns 3 etc.
for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
    $pattern2 = "";
    $pattern2 = sprintf($pattern, $input[$i]);
    if ($i < ($c - 1)) { // the last LIKE statement should not have AND
        $pattern2 .= "AND ";
    }
    $query .= $pattern2;
}
echo $query // SELECT * FROM plates WHERE number LIKE '%8%' AND number LIKE '%7%' AND number LIKE '%6%' AND number LIKE '%5%'
```

Comment: the user will search '786' and also the search key may be 4 digit or 5 digit or 2 digit means may be they will search '78'  so we need to explode the digits? any other quick solution?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to split string,

```
$arr = str_split("786");
array_walk($arr, function (&$item) {
    $item = '"%' . $item . '%"';
});
$in_clause = rtrim(implode(" OR ", $arr), 'OR ');

$query = "select * from plates where number $in_clause";
```

I hope this will help.